# Ubuntu 17.10 - UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY (i.e: without -a or -p options). How to fix?

Tags: boot

I'm using dual boot: Ubuntu 17.10 along with Windows 7. Recently I'm facing an issue when I want to boot Ubuntu. It shows: "UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY".
I run **fsck /dev/sda6**
But it does not work.
Can anyone tell me how can I fix that issue?

Thanks

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate of what *I think that you have already read*  -  You need to interpret the command to match your system however:  The disk that needs fsck may not be '/dev/sda6', and unless you show us the full error, we cannot tell you which disk needs the operation.

Comment: Check it here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2jwubfk0mfefm5k/20180110_205640.jpg?dl=0

Comment: When you run `fsck -f /dev/sda6`, does anything appear in the terminal window?

Comment: It appear some text along with a number ( which maybe memory address or location ) and prompt for y/n. I just type y and it perform some operation again prompt for y/n, again I type y and again some operations. This run continuously....

Comment: That means it is doing something to fix the errors that it finds.  If sitting there pressing 'y' is getting boring, you could run the command as `fsck -fy /dev/sda6`

Comment: After a certain period of time it shows the following messges continuously: systemd-logind[a_number]: Failed to enable subscription: Connection timed out.  systemd-logind[a_number]: Failed to fully start up daemon: Connection timed out.   systemd[a_number]: Failed to start Login Service.